# Strange behaviour of getFocus() on EditTexts

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

So I'm having three EditText- boxes and when the user presses enter in one of them I want to move on the next one.

I tried:

```
final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
email.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

            findViewById(R.id.editText2).requestFocus();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});


final EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
pass.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

            findViewById(R.id.editText3).requestFocus();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});



final EditText passrep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
passrep.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

            findViewById(R.id.button1).requestFocus();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

but with this code the focus jumps from editText1 to editText3 on keyboard enter.

What works is this (which i found out by accident):

```
final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
email.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

            findViewById(R.id.editText2).requestFocus();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});


final EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
email.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

            findViewById(R.id.editText3).requestFocus();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});



final EditText passrep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
email.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

            findViewById(R.id.button1).requestFocus();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

e.g., setting three different OnKeyListeners all for the same EditText (email).

What am I missing here? This is my layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="234dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="Email" >

</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="234dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="Password" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="234dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="Confirm Password" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="123dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:text="@string/submit" />
```

Comment: So what happens with your current implementation?

Comment: is this not a alternative solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048586/can-you-set-tab-order-in-xml-layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what is happening here is all of your `EditText`s are listening for key event **ALL THE TIME** whether they are in focus or not

You need to use `OnEditorActionListener` for Done/Enter/Go/Search key

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            //do something
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```