# Use tab to change focus in an android application

Tags: android, focus

i am new to android programming.
I want to use TAB(in keyboard) to change focus to the next edittext box.
Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you set "tab order" in XML Layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048586/can-you-set-tab-order-in-xml-layout)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Xml attribute `android:nextFocusDown` in all your EditText

If you want to use this programmatically (without using Xml attribute)

```
private void setUpView(){
    editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
 }
private void setDownFocus(){
    editText1.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.editText2);
    editText2.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.editText3);// you can give focus to any id
    editText3.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.editText1);
 }
```

In **onCreate()** call **setUpView()** before **setDownFocus()**

Comment: @Sourav this will be handled by the System,you don't need to write java code.
How you have write you xml?can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XML on your layout

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Enter Name"/>

         <requestFocus />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to intercept the TAB key press and jump to the next element on screen.
What I did was to extend EditText and override the "onKeyDown" method so it would send the focus to the next element.
Here is my simple extension to EditText:

```
package my.package;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TabExitEditText extends EditText {

    public TabExitEditText(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    public TabExitEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TabExitEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB) {
            focusSearch(FOCUS_RIGHT).requestFocus();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

In the layout you just set

```
<my.package.TabExitEditText
   ... 
   android:nextFocusRight="@id/nextRightFocusId"
/>
```

You can customize to use other focus direction order.