# Jumping between EditTexts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have XML layout with 4 EditTexts, but then i focusing on first enter smth, and click next button from mobile keybord, cursor jumps to last edittext, how can i fix it and everytime then I enter smth and click next I jump to the next, not last EditText.

Comment: Next does not skip to last.

Comment: try with giving tag to every `EditText`.

Comment: I guess you are looking for someething like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048586/can-you-set-tab-order-in-xml-layout